# Invalid character \u001f when using compression-webpack-plugin on iphone webview locally

Tags: javascript, webpack, compression, babeljs

I seem to be having an issue when using webpack-compression-plugin that i think only appears locally for iphone/ios webview. When I reference my compressed assets, the iphone webview gives the following error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u001f
```

When I disable the compression plugin, this problem goes away. This only seems to be happening locally.
[image]

Comment: running into this as well...